# Prototypal Inheritance: Copying a function prototype to another

Tags: javascript, oop

What is the harm in copying the prototype of a function to another function like shown below.

```
function Person(){}
Person.prototype = {};
function Author(){}
Author.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

Comment: Among other problems, the `constructor` property on the prototype will be set incorrectly. You want `Author.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);`.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for raising this matter. But Author.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); will not set the correct constructor of the prototype. You will have to manually set it back to the original function anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object assignments in JS create a reference.

```
var o = {};
var c = o;
```

Now both the objects `o` and `c` are referring to the same object. Same rule applies when trying to assign the prototype of one object to another.

```
Author.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

Now the prototypes of both `Author` and `Person` refers to a single object. If you put some data to a prototype property of the `Author`, the same data will be there for the Person too. This is least expected for distinct objects.

One of the proper ways of doing this is

```
Author.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

Here you create a brand new object for `Author.prototype` - but inheriting from `Person` object.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're passing the prototype by reference, which means both are affected by all changes.  Consider:

```
function Person(){}
Person.prototype = {};
function Author(){}
Author.prototype = Person.prototype;

Author.prototype.books = [];

var bob = new Person();
console.log(bob.books); // this will be an empty array, not undefined as one would expect.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ideal way of attaching methods to prototype is by creating an object which is created by instance.

```
function Person(){
   this.test = "1";
}
function Author(){}
Author.prototype = new Person();
```

this way you create a new instance of person and returned object is fed into Author.

What if you simply copy it ?

If you simply copy the same instance is shared across prototypes , change in one prototype will be reflected in all.

```
function b(){
    this.test = 'a';
    this.test1 = function(){
        console.log('test1');
    }
    this.test2 = function(){
        console.log('test2');
    }
}
function a(){

}
function c(){

}
a.prototype = new b();
var a1 = new a();
c.prototype = a.prototype;
a.test = 'asdf';
console.log(c.test);
```

Uniqueness of data to an instance will be missing.